# i have been experiencing this error after upgrading my android studio to 4.2

Tags: android

Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/flatbuffers/flatbuffers-java/1.12.0/flatbuffers-java-1.12.0.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `mavenCentral()` to your build.gradle `allproject.repositories` block.

Comment: I also had to put it in `buildscript.repositories` to fix this.